# The maincontent is accessible from Navigation drawer frame.

Tags: android, android-listview, navigation-drawer, empty-list

i am using the following xml file in navigation drawer

**XML:**

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->



    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >






    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"

    >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="Login"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/DisplayImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/displayimage" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/contentdescription"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Displayname"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/counter_text_color"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="@string/Signin"
            android:gravity = "center"
             />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@color/card_background"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        />

       <include android:id="@+id/progressinformation" layout="@layout/emptyview"/>

      <View
         android:id="@+id/view1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="2dp"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_below="@+id/header"
         android:layout_marginTop="2dp" 
         android:layout_marginBottom="2dp" 
         android:background="@color/card_background"

       />

</RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

i am setting **include** as an Empty view for **left_drawer** (left_drawer.setEmptyView(R.id.progressinformation)).

my problem is,  suppose if listview is empty when i click on the navigation drawer the elements behind the navigation drawer are selecting. how to avoid this selection when listview is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if understand correctly but you have to set navigation drawer layout param clickable to true

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_frame"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:clickable="true"
    >
```